# Getting the random values in the new array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a new array from a array. And i am getting the random values.(something like-858993460) This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int m = 8;
        int i, k;
        int A[m] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    int B[m];
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0) {
            A[i] = B[i];
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << B[k];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're never actually assigning anything to `B`.

Comment: A[i] = B[i]; Doesn't that give the values to b ???

Comment: @ShkelqimMaxharraj: And `k = k + 1` gives a new value to `k + 1` ?

Comment: Yeah. That is used for the next element (if exists) if it doesn't then leave the k as the size of B[]

Comment: "Doesn't that give the values to b" - Assuming you meant `B` and not `b` (since there is no `b` in this code) *What* values to `B`?? You never put any values in any elements in `B[]`. What were you *expecting*? If you're going to say, "this isn't right" you'd better know what *is* right, which isn't possible in this code, as the content in `B[]` is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Usually, left hand side of operator "=" is the destination, the right hand side is the source .. so A[i] = 3, sets A[i] to 3.  It DOESNT give 3 the value of A[i].

Comment: Even if i say B[i] = A[i]; it doesn't give me the right values. Soo ...

Comment: `m`, `i`, `A`, `k`, `B` = code obfuscation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    const int m = 8;
    int i, k;
    int A[m] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    int B[m];
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0) {
            B[k] = A[i];
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        cout << B[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference. And is this working for you cuz it doesn't for me

Comment: I'm assigning value from array A to B not B to A because A has already predefined value.

Comment: @ShkelqimMaxharraj copy and paste this code, I tested it's work fine for me,